# How to convert Spring Boot configuration meta-data files to HTML

Tags: spring-boot

I'm sure there must be an elegant way to turn [Spring Boot configuration meta-data files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html) into HTML (or markdown or ...). While I *could* write a parser myself I'm convinced that this has already been solved. Yet, I failed to find a lead for that so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/indrabasak/stackoverflow-indra/tree/master/spring-test-examples) is a simple example of converting Spring Boot configuration metadata into HTML using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor` and `org.freemarker:freemarker` libraries.

[image]

#### Parse Metadata

Use classes from `spring-boot-configuration-processor` library to parse the JSON file,

```
File metadataFile = new File("spring-configuration-metadata.json");
ConfigurationMetadata metadata =
                new JsonMarshaller().read(new FileInputStream(metadataFile));
```

#### HTML Generation

Once you have the metadata converted into Java object, use `FreeMarker` templated to convert it into an HTML file. It uses `metadata.ftl` template to convert the `metadata` object into `metadata.html`.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(new Version(2, 3, 27));

// template is loaded from 'templates' folder under resources
cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(
    SpringConfigurationMetadataProcessorTest.class, "/templates");
cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
cfg.setLocale(Locale.US);
cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(
    TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);

Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<String, Object>();
input.put("title", "Spring Configuration Metadata Example");
input.put("metadata", metadata);
input.put("GROUP", ItemMetadata.ItemType.GROUP);
input.put("PROPERTY", ItemMetadata.ItemType.PROPERTY);

Template template = cfg.getTemplate("metadata.ftl");

// write output into a file
Writer fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("metadata.html"));
try {
    template.process(input, fileWriter);
} finally {
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

Here is the example `metadata.ftl`,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>${title}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${title}</h1>

<#if metadata.hints??>
<section>
    <h1>Hints</h1>
    <#list metadata.hints as hint>
        <section>
        <dl>
            <dt><b>name: </b>${hint.name}</dt>
            <#if hint.values?? && hint.values?size != 0>
                <dt><b>values:</b></dt>
                <#list hint.values as value>
                    <#if value.value??>
                        <dd><b>value: </b>${value.value}</dd>
                    </#if>
                    <#if value.description??>
                        <dd><b>description: </b>${value.description}</dd>
                    </#if>
                    <br/>
                </#list>
            </#if>
            <#if hint.providers?? && hint.providers?size != 0>
                <dt><b>providers:</b></dt>
                <#list hint.providers as provider>
                    <#if provider.name??>
                        <dd><b>name: </b>${provider.name}</dd>
                    </#if>
                    <#if provider.parameters?? && provider.parameters?size != 0>
                        <dd><b>parameters:</b></dd>
                        <#list provider.parameters as key, value>
                            <dd>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>${key}: </b>${value}
                            </dd>
                        </#list>
                    </#if>
                    <br/>
                </#list>
            </dl>
            </#if>
        </section>
    </#list>
</section>
</#if>

<#if metadata.items??>
<section>
    <h1>Groups</h1>
    <#list metadata.items as item>
        <#if item.isOfItemType(GROUP)>
            <section>
                <dl>
                    <#if item.sourceType??>
                        <dt><b>sourceType: </b> ${item.sourceType}</dt>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.name??>
                        <dt><b>name: </b> ${item.name}</dt>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.description??>
                        <dt><b>description: </b> ${item.description}</dt>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.type??>
                        <dt><b>type: </b> ${item.type}</dt>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.sourceMethod??>
                        <dt><b>sourceMethod: </b> ${item.sourceMethod}</dt>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.defaultValue??>
                        <#if item.defaultValue?is_enumerable>
                            <dt><b>defaultValue: </b></dt>
                            <#list item.defaultValue as df>
                                <dd>${df}</dd>
                            </#list>
                        <#else>
                            <dt><b>defaultValue: </b> ${item.defaultValue}</dt>
                        </#if>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.deprecation??>
                        <dt><b>deprecation: </b></dt>
                        <#if item.deprecation.reason??>
                            <dd><b>reason: </b> ${item.deprecation.reason}</dd>
                        </#if>
                        <#if item.deprecation.replacement??>
                            <dd><b>replacement: </b> ${item.deprecation.replacement}</dd>
                        </#if>
                        <#if item.deprecation.level??>
                            <dd><b>level: </b> ${item.deprecation.level}</dd>
                        </#if>
                    </#if>
                </dl>
            </section>
        </#if>
    </#list>
    <h1>Properties</h1>
    <#list metadata.items as item>
        <#if item.isOfItemType(PROPERTY)>
            <section>
                <dl>
                    <#if item.sourceType??>
                        <dt><b>sourceType: </b> ${item.sourceType}</dt>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.name??>
                        <dt><b>name: </b> ${item.name}</dt>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.description??>
                        <dt><b>description: </b> ${item.description}</dt>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.type??>
                        <dt><b>type: </b> ${item.type}</dt>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.sourceMethod??>
                        <dt><b>sourceMethod: </b> ${item.sourceMethod}</dt>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.defaultValue??>
                        <#if item.defaultValue?is_enumerable>
                            <dt><b>defaultValue: </b></dt>
                            <#list item.defaultValue as df>
                                <dd>${df}</dd>
                            </#list>
                        <#else>
                            <dt><b>defaultValue: </b> ${item.defaultValue}</dt>
                        </#if>
                    </#if>
                    <#if item.deprecation??>
                        <dt><b>deprecation: </b></dt>
                        <#if item.deprecation.reason??>
                            <dd><b>reason: </b> ${item.deprecation.reason}</dd>
                        </#if>
                        <#if item.deprecation.replacement??>
                            <dd><b>replacement: </b> ${item.deprecation.replacement}</dd>
                        </#if>
                        <#if item.deprecation.level??>
                            <dd><b>level: </b> ${item.deprecation.level}</dd>
                        </#if>
                    </#if>
                </dl>
            </section>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</section>
</#if>

</body>
</html>
```