# Spring configuration. Generate documentation for all configuration keys

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javadoc

Is there any way to generate Javadoc-like documentation that contains only Spring Configuration keys with description and default values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible with [Spring Boot Configuration Metadata](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.8/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#appendix.configuration-metadata) and then [conversion to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47765740/328982)